Finding Button with Selenium in Python without Name or ID
I am new to Selenium and I am facing a problem, where I have to click on a button which has no ID or Name.
I already tried to find the element by XPath and CSS Selector. The outcome is with both methods the same: The Driver can not find such Element.
HTML: HTML
CSS Selector:
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button_text").click()

XPath:
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//form\[@data-g-name='Button'\]")


Your locators are incorrect. Can you share the URL of the page if it's public?

https://www.bossard.com/eshop/ch-en/cart/
Thanks for your help, you will need to navigate to "Upload from Excel"

Use this XPath - //form[@id='uploadXls']//button

Thanks the Element was found but the following Error  Message occurred:
element not interactable
Code: driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//form[@id='uploadXls']//button").click()

element not interactable because that element is disabled. You need to upload an excel file first to enable this button. Check the code in my answer.

Check the code below with explanation:
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.bossard.com/eshop/ch-en/cart/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

# Click on accept all cookies pop-up, use this code if you see the cookie pop-up
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "_evidon-banner-acceptbutton"))).click()

# click on Upload from Excel
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Upload from Excel']"))).click()

# upload excel
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//form[@id='uploadXls']//input[@type='file']"))).send_keys("C:/full/path/of/the/file/test.xlsx")

# Click on Add to cart button
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//form[@id='uploadXls']//button"))).click()
time.sleep(20)


Wow, thanks for your Quick Solution. Now it works completely fine.
I don't really understand how you define the Xpath

An article about relative XPath just refer it if it helps, - XPath in Selenium: How to Find & Write? (Text, Contains, AND)

ok, Thank you very much
